# iOS RealityKit error: Attempting to form more than one copy of a bag

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

I am seeing this error in my RealityKit app, but I cannot find any info about it online. Does anyone have any more to add? Thanks very much.

```
RealityFoundation/OrderedCoatCheckBag.swift:183: Fatal error: Attempting to form more than one copy of a bag. These should be held by at most one reference type.
```